# Dynamic Meta Tag is not working in firebase using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, firebase, meta-tags

I am trying to show thumbnail and description when i share link on Facebook but its show nothing. I think its because Fire-base image take time to load. When i enter static meta-tag it works perfectly. 
I am using  **JavaScript and Fire-base**
MetaTag came on fire-base response

```
<meta property="og:type" content="blog">
<meta property="og:title" content="Deforestation is increasing and is resulting in more and more climate change">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ecology-watch.appspot.com/o/images%2FB8ED1359-C869-4041-8550-38B9A2B6A812?alt=media&token=a66c42cf-fb15-4347-8824-b5f3265668f2">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300">
```

Comment: Facebook's crawlers do not execute JavaScript, so everything must be present on first page load. If you're using Firebase Hosting, you can use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) to do server-side rendering of your `<meta>` tags.